# How to execute linux binary from MSYS

Tags: msys

I wanted to try a program distributed in source for *nux on Windows. It's simple program with couple of C source files and headers

1. I have Mingw/Msys and first I tried to compile it there, by running `make`, but unfortunatelly I get obscure error `(.text+0x175): undefined reference to 'strsep'` which maight indicate a problem with autotools or similar, according Google search, but that's all about it I could get
2. As I mentioned that it is a simple program, I also tried to compile it with VS2008, until I figured it uses unix header file for parsing command line arguments, so nothing I can do there too
3. I launched my Ubuntu laptop and compiled the program in second, and tested it all fine, then I copy binary in my Windows Msys folder. No luck again as file can't be execeted (under Msys prompt of course) - it doesn't have execute flag and `chmod` on Msys has a "feature" that makes `chmod +x` unavailable

---

**Update:**

This is the error I get from msys prompt while trying to compile:

```
f77_diagram.c: In function 'handle_goto':
f77_diagram.c:57:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strsep' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
[...]
gcc  -o f77_diagram block.o do_loop.o f77_diagram.o if.o label.o \
                                  links.o parse_fortran.o
f77_diagram.o:f77_diagram.c:(.text+0x175): undefined reference to `strsep'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the function/variable strsep wasn't properly initialized. It most likely is a linking error. All it probably means is that you don't have a dependency installed. You'll need to post more information about the error.

By the way, you can't run linux binaries on windows.

Judging by your error, it looks like your compiler doesn't support the strsep function. To deal with this you will probably have to code your own, like this:

```
char *strsep(char **from, const char *delim) {
    char *s, *dp, *ret;

    if ((s = *from) == NULL)
        return NULL;

    ret = s;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        /* loop until the end of s, checking against each delimiting character,
         * if we find a delimiter set **s to '\0' and return our previous token
         * to the user. */
        dp = (char *)delim;
        while (*dp != '\0') {
            if (*s == *dp) {
                *s = '\0';
                *from = s + 1;
                return ret;
            }
            dp++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    /* end of string case */
    *from = NULL;
    return ret;
}
```

Here is the process that you will have to go through:

1- Find the file f77_diagram.c in the src directory.

2- Copy and paste the above code right after the `#include` statements.

3- Return to your command shell in the main make directory.

4- Re-run `./configure`

5- Re-run `make`

If this doesn't work, there are a few other things you could try.

Comment: Thanks, now I get `warning: implicit declaration of function 'STD'` and `error: called object 'STD(&strchr)' is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, I gave you c++ source code. I changed it above so it sohuld work with C. This isn't my code by the way, I got it here: http://ithildin.org/trac/browser/trunk/ithildin/source/contrib/strsep.c?rev=744

Answer (score 0):

MSYS provides a Linux-like build environment for Windows. However, Linux binaries use the ELF or A.OUT formats, rather than the EXE format. Since there is nothing like WINE for Windows, Linux binaries have to be recompiled for Windows.